# Dynamic datetime value for a header as condition for mod_rewrite apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory './output/' with images which are only accessible if a header ('testheader') with the value 'tst' has been send by the browser. It works by these lines in .htaccess using mod_rewrite. The .htaccess file is located in './output/':

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond "%{HTTP:testheader}" !tst
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

To test it I'm running this code on my webserver:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob'; //so you can access the response like a normal URL
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
};
xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.example.com/output/down.png', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('testheader','tst');
xhr.send();
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

This verifies and works great, when changing values of the 'testheader'!

Now I want to go next-level and create a more dynamic solution, I want to feed the 'testheader' with a dynamic date time value, YYYYMMDD, for example '20220817'. If the header that is send is smaller than this integer, it should be forbidden.

Reading through the manuals

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

https://harrybailey.com/2015/08/htaccess-redirects-based-on-date-and-time/

I came up with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:testheader} <%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Now with the above code I set the header like this:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('testheader','20220817'); //should be changed to current date
```

But whatever date I have set, now the images in './output/' are always blocked.

Maybe my syntax in .htaccess is wrong? I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use '%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}' on the right side of the equation in RewriteCond.

Hope one of you out there has a brilliant solution!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

It was just there in the manual under section 5.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Using the 'expr' with -strmatch, it does as requested.
With this .htaccess the issue is addressed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond expr "! %{HTTP:testheader} -strmatch '%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}'"
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```